# undefined reference to full template specialization class member function, but not partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

so i got an undefined reference error when using template explicit instantiation with full template class specialization, but the question is, partial template class specialization goes well without error.

code shows as below, do anyone know why? what's the difference between full specialization and partial specialization in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

```
// t.h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2> 
class A { 
  public:
  void foo();
};

// t2.cpp
#include "t.h"

template<typename T1> 
class A<T1, int> {
  public:
  void foo() {
    cout << "T1, int" << endl;
  }
};

template<>
class A<int, int> {
  public:
  void foo() {
    cout << "int, int" << endl;
  }
};

template class A<float, int>;
template class A<int, int>;

// t.cpp
#include "t.h"

int main() {
  A<float, int> a;
  a.foo();  // no error
  A<int, int> a1; 
  a1.foo(); // undefined reference error, why?
  return 0;
}
```

the compile commands are `g++ t.cpp t2.cpp -o t` with gcc 4.8.5.

Comment: Please include build chain details: Compiler? Linker?  Flags?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont add it at the end, thanks

Comment: Don’t put using directives in header files like that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **declare** [partial](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#1) and [explicit](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#6) specializations in **every** translation unit that uses them (before any use that would implicitly instantiate that specialization).  Here, that would look like

```
template<class T> class A<T,int>;
template<> class A<int,int>;
```

immediately after the primary template (to avoid any possibility of erroneous implicit instantiation.

Compilers have historically been “lax” about this, which is to say that sometimes it does what you’d expect from an analysis of all source files together.

You’ve found the edge of such accidental “support” in this particular compiler.

Comment: Can you show me how to modify the code above to fulfill the standardization? that is, how to declare partial and explicit specialization in every translation unit? thanks in advance

Comment: @NiuChong: Since you can declare them and then define them, you can do it just once in the header: edited.

Comment: i added the code you gave at the end of the header file, but it got another error of 'error: aggregate ‘A<float, int> a’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined'

Comment: @NiuChong: Sorry, I was thinking only of preventing the *linker* error.  If you need the specializations to be *complete* in (most of) the client translation units, just put the specialization *definitions* in the header, like any other class.

Comment: thanks, guess i still need to modify the above usage of template class specialization.